# Http GET request parameter as query parameter and header

Tags: java, http

I need to send parameters through **HTTP GET** request. Since my HTTP client has to be generic, I am adding the parameters as query parameter `(?key=value&k=v)` and also as request `header (key: value)`.

Is this a good approach? Will the server looking for header ignore query parameters or vice versa?

Please suggest.

Comment: I don't see the point of adding request headers for parameters. Just use the query parameters - that's what they are there for. In addition, caches may not maintain your custom headers.

Comment: **Headers should be used to data related to the HTTP protocol**, not to the application. For sending data without being in the _query_string_, you use methods like POST.

Comment: Requirement for me is that the recipient of my request may look in the header also. Currently I have provided one UI to enter parameter name and value. I need to know if I set it in both places, will the recipient ignore query parameter?

Comment: Then your requirement is stupid. Even if you put that information in the headers, there's no guarantee it will make it to the receiving end. Custom headers can and may be stripped at any time. And your question doesn't make sense. First you say that the recipient may look in the headers, then you ask what they'll do with the query parameter. Nobody can know that except the recipient.

Answer (score 5):

As per the convention, you should set the request parameter for GET request in the query string. Headers are used for passing message/meta information along with the request. So use headers to set that information only, such as Content-Type,Accept.

Avoid mixing the headers and request params.